# 401 when using createAccountHolders api

Tags: adyen

Why I get 401 and no error message when I want to create an account holder ?

I make a request with https://reqbin.com

```
URL: https://cal-test.adyen.com/cal/services/Account/v6/createAccountHolder
headers:
x-API-key: xxx

method: POST,

content (body)
{
   "accountHolderCode":"TestAccountHolder5691",
   "accountHolderDetails":{
      "address": {
        "country": "DE"
      },
      "email":"test@dasdas.com",
      "individualDetails":{
         "name":{
            "firstName":"First name",
            "gender":"MALE",
            "lastName":"Last Name"
         }
      }
   },
   "createDefaultAccount":true,
   "legalEntity":"Individual"
}
```

Comment: `401` is typically authorization error, check the API Key you are passing (maybe no longer valid? is for the `test` env?). Everything else seems correct.

Comment: @BeppeC all is correct because I use the same api key to make request from other apis and in there it works... maybe I need a sub mechant marketplace account but idk how to create this

Comment: Yes, thats correct, different API key, I have added an answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `API Key` required by the CAL api is different from the API key used for processing payments.

The API credentials for marketplace have typically the format `<username>@MarketPlace.<account code>` and unfortunately you cannot create that via the Customer Area web app.
Reach out to Adyen Support to request the creation of the credential: you can then manage them (i.e. generate API key, config Basic Auth) yourself in the CA.

Comment: I wait 2 week for a response from adyen but nothing happens, are there any other contact methods ?

Comment: Strange, it shouldnt take so long. Did you try this https://www.adyen.help/hc/en-us/requests/new?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will take a look and send another request.